# Update page on drop-down list selection change

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

So I am an asp.net and razor pages beginner, and I've been trying to rework a WPF project of mine into a web program.

My current hurdle is trying to properly get a report to update when a drop-down has the selection changed. This drop-down is currently populated by an enum of report types, and generated by this code.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedReport,
                          Html.GetEnumSelectList(Model.SelectedReport.GetType()),
                          "Select Report",
                          new {@id = "ReportDropdown", @onchange = "UpdateReport()"})
```

I ended up with this function to handle the onchange event.

```
function UpdateReport() {
    var reportID = $("ReportDropdown").val();

    $.ajax
        ({
            url: '/Reporting/UpdateReport',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'application/JSON',
            contentType: 'application/JSON',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                reportID: +reportID
            }),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result)
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("That wasn't right.")
            }
        });
}
```

Which I believe works because the "That wasn't right." alert will fire when I change the selection. But at this point I can't figure out why the report wont update with this PageModel code.

```
public class ReportingModel : PageModel
{
    public DataView Report { get; private set; }

    [Display(Name ="Selected Report")]
    public ReportGenerator.ReportTypes SelectedReport { get; set; }

    public ReportGenerator generator { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        generator = new ReportGenerator()
        {
            SelectedReport = ReportGenerator.ReportTypes.DailySummary
        };

        Report = generator.Report.DefaultView;

        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateReport()
    {
        generator.SelectedReport = SelectedReport;

        this.Report = generator.Report.DefaultView;

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to get this working, or is there a better way I can leverage to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there a refresh option for the reports? I've never used Razor, so this is just a educated guess in the circumstances.

Comment: Why is there a plus (+) sign in your post data in front of reportID?

Comment: @SANM2009 If there is I haven't found it, I've only been able to load it when the page is requested so far.

Comment: @MiklósTóth I'm not the best with javascript, but if I take the plus sign out the report ID never gets sent in the request. With the plus sign I can see reportID in the parameters of the request but it's null.